# RuntimeException for xpath

Tags: java, dom, xpath, runtimeexception

i have a function which in this function, i use Xpath to get the position of a node as below:

```
   Node goTo;
.....


private Node xpathgo(Node node) throws XPathExpressionException {
       XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
       Node result;

 if (node == null || node.getNodeName() == null){
            return null;
        }

               xpathgo(node.getFirstChild());


               result =   (Node) xpath.evaluate("//*[. = \"" + goTo.getNodeValue() + "\"]", node,XPathConstants.NODE);


            xpathgo(node.getNextSibling());
 return  result;   
}
```

basically i use this to get a node of a DOM which made from a URL html code, but i face two problems with it, firstly, sometimes i get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve the node to a handle
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault.getDTMHandleFromNode(DTMManagerDefault.java:574)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPathContext.getDTMHandleFromNode(XPathContext.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.execute(XPath.java:301)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.eval(XPathImpl.java:210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:275)
```

and also this one for some other kind of nodes:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Expected ], but found: the
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.error(XPathParser.java:608)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.consumeExpected(XPathParser.java:526)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.Predicate(XPathParser.java:1935)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.Step(XPathParser.java:1724)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.RelativeLocationPath(XPathParser.java:1624)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.LocationPath(XPathParser.java:1595)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.PathExpr(XPathParser.java:1315)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.UnionExpr(XPathParser.java:1234)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.UnaryExpr(XPathParser.java:1140)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.MultiplicativeExpr(XPathParser.java:1061)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.AdditiveExpr(XPathParser.java:1003)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.RelationalExpr(XPathParser.java:928)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.EqualityExpr(XPathParser.java:868)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.AndExpr(XPathParser.java:832)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.OrExpr(XPathParser.java:805)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.Expr(XPathParser.java:788)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.initXPath(XPathParser.java:127)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.<init>(XPath.java:176)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.<init>(XPath.java:264)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.eval(XPathImpl.java:193)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:275)
... 7 more
```

but the funny thing is, in booth cases, the nodes are a `[#text]` node which made me confused why it happens.

Comment: I don't know in detail what these errors mean, but I do see that your code isn't doing anything smart about the case where goTo.getNodeValue() contains quotation marks.

Comment: @MichaelKay question mark? why that? it says expected ] and found the and nothing about question mark and for other one the error says cant send the node to handler, where did u get the idea of question mark?